# How to make factory method with variadic templates work, also dynamically?

Tags: c++, templates

I have implemented a factory funtion based on variadic template, since the constructors have different number of parameters, unfortunately I am unable to make it work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct Animal {
    virtual void sound() = 0;
}; 

struct Dog : public Animal{
    Dog(std::string name, int age){}
    void sound() override {
        std::cout << "Wuf" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct Cat : public Animal {
    Cat(std::string name){}
    void sound() override {
        std::cout << "Miaw" << std::endl;
    }
};

template<typename... Ts>
std::unique_ptr<Animal> AnimalFactory(bool b, Ts&&... params) {
    switch (b) {
        case (true):
            return std::make_unique<Dog>(std::forward<Ts>(params)...);
        case (false):
            return std::make_unique<Cat>(std::forward<Ts>(params)...);
    }
}

int main()
{
    auto c = AnimalFactory(false, std::string("bad cat"));
    c->sound();
    auto d = AnimalFactory(true, std::string("good boy"),6);
    d->sound();
    return 0;
}
```

This might be a good solution, but this can only work in compile time? Is there a possibility to use this method dynamically?

Comment: What should happen for `AnimalFactor(false, std::string("good boy"),6)` or `AnimalFactor(true, std::string("bad cat"))`? You might do though `AnimalFactor<true>( std::string("good boy"), 6)` (or even better `AnimalFactor<Dog>(std::string("good boy"),6)`) but then factory is not dynamic...

Comment: Simple answer: Templates are compile time and there is really nothing which can changed later during runtime. As this the answer is NO!

Comment: understandible, is there a way to achieve this than without the usage of templates?  the major complication is that the number and type of arguments is not the same